# Factorial function using JS

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code that accepts numbers and prints their factorial to the console.

This time, I wanna make it PROMPT a user for the number and then ALERT the factorial.

```js
var x = prompt("Input the number" );
var y=1;
function factorial(x) {
  for(i=2; i<=x; i++) {
    y *= i;
  }
  console.log(y);
}
alert(factorial(x));
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the code you have, so far? Have you tried using the [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) command?

Comment: It says my code is incorrect and won't post. And I need 10 reputations to post images.... Kindly write me a new one.

Comment: Try including the post using indentation of 4 spaces instead of the HTML snippet editor

Comment: var x = prompt("Input the number" );
var y=1;
function factorial(x) {
for(i=2; i<=x; i++) {
y *= i;
}
console.log(y);
}
alert(factorial(x));

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, you only forgot to actually return the value of `y` as the result of your function.

```js
var x = prompt("Input the number" );
var y=1;
function factorial(x) {
  for(i=2; i<=x; i++) {
    y *= i;
  }
  console.log(y);
  return y;
}
alert(factorial(x));
```

Note the `return y` statement I have added.